# insert 'print rand' into DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

I am trying to insert a random 8 digit number into a DB

Here is the code I'm using to generate the random number

```
'insert 'print rand' into DB '
```

Here is my current insert code

```
     mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con); $sql="
   INSERT INTO member (title,firstname,lastname,daytimetel,mob,work,email,
   address1,address2,towncity,postcode,country,password,phrase,businesstype,businesscontact,regno,regcountry,pos,created) 

  VALUES('$title','$firstname','$lastname','$daytimetel','$mob','$work','$email',
   '$address1','$address2','$towncity','$postcode','$country','$password','$phrase','$businesstype','$businesscontact','$regno','$regcountry','$pos','$created')";
```

how would I insert this?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: where is your PHP code

Comment: @Sundar I have added my php code

Comment: i can't understand print rand what you are trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number, use [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand):

```
$number = mt_rand( 10000000, 99999999);
```

To store it in the database, insert it with [`PDO`](http://php.net/PDO):

```
$pdo = new PDO( '', $db_username, $db_password); // read the docs for this
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable (column_name) VALUES ( ? )');
$stmt->execute( array( $number));
```

this is your query in general

```
   INSERT INTO your_table (your_column_name) VALUES ( '$number' )
```